# Is a blade grinder or burr grinder best for grinding coffee?

Tags: espresso, grinder

I have recently received some vouchers and have gotten into coffee recently. I what to start buying my own beans and grinding them rather than just buying instant coffee or even already ground coffee, as I'm told beans newly ground beans that have also been recently roasted are way way better tasting and are what you should do if you're getting serious about coffee. However, there seems to be a lot of different blade grinders and also different [burr grinders](http://coffee-grinders.co.uk/best-coffee-grinder-top-12-review/). Some seem to say a burr grinder is a must, but they seem to be more expensive. Which should I get if I'd really like to get into my coffee?

Apparently burr grinders are far better if you want to change the coarseness of you your coffee whereas a blade grinder will basically just chop it up.

Which type of grinder is best for grinding coffee?

Comment: Definitely burr grinder. And definitely a duplicate. :) See also other related questions tagged [tag:grinder] and [tag:burr-grinder]. Welcome to [coffee.se]! See also the [tour] for more information on finding content within [se] sites.